# why my else cannoot execute while the statement is else?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I want to create a login page script with the username and password as the data account from db. n then when my input is doesn't match the else didn't execute while username and password is did not exist in db. so what should i do to fix this. any somebody help me please

```
def logindb():
print ("=="*15+"\nPlease insert your username and password.")
username = input ("Username : ")
password = input ("Password : ")
cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM data WHERE username='{username}' and password='{password}'")
result = cursor.fetchall()
for i in result:
    if (i[0]) == username and (i[1]) == password:
        print ("=="*15+"\n\tLogin Success.\n"+"=="*15)
    else:
        print ("=="*15+"\nUsername or password is wrong.\n"+"=="*15)
```

Comment: What's your table structure look like for your `data` table?

Comment: Check the status for `cursor.execute`. Check that `result` contains correct values. Check the positions of tested columns. `for` statement is correct itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code snippet, the statement can **NEVER** be else!

You query for a database entries matching username and password. For every entry (with the matching username and password) you again check if these credentials are correct.

I guess what you want, is to check **if** there are records found.

Something like this:

```py
result = cursor.fetchall()
if (len(result) > 0):
    print ("=="*15+"\n\tLogin Success.\n"+"=="*15)
else:
    print ("=="*15+"\nUsername or password is wrong.\n"+"=="*15)
```

Side note: you really should hash the password instead of saving it as plain text in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM data WHERE username='{username}' and password='{password}'")
```

To:

```
cursor.execute(f"SELECT username, password FROM data WHERE username='{username}' and password='{password}'")
```

You're selecting `ALL*` columns, and if your 0 index column is not `username`, and your 1 index column is not `password`, your query result will not match up your submitted `username` and `password`.

```
if (i[0]) == username and (i[1]) == password:
```

It's also not a good idea to run your `SELECT` statements wide open if you don't need to. *Retrieve only the columns explicitly that you need to retrieve.*

Answer (score 0):

You should really use a parameterized query.

But if you are going to use this method of data retrieval then I would go one step further then Griv's answer

```py
cursor.execute(f"SELECT userid FROM data WHERE username='{username}' and password='{password}'")
```

I would **never fetch the username or password**.  Instead, check for its existence by fetching the primary key of the table.

Then check if that value is **null** or not.

I am not familiar with python, I assume the **f"SELECT** is not a typo